# express issue with req.headers - I can't find some parameters

Tags: express

I have an issue with req.headers. When I send request from `localhost` I see all parameters which I send, but when I try to send it from Azure server domain ( API on AWS ) .. it isn't working ( for example `google.com/api/request` .. What can it be? Maybe I should give an access or smth else..?

[image]

Above you can see how did I send request .. ( I send it from some real domain not from localhost ) - when I send it from localhost , I see parameter `access_token`  . I try to find it in `req.headers.access_token`

Comment: You should tell us what you expect to see, what you are seeing, how you're making the API calls (postman, curl, the nodejs "request" library, etc). Please provide as much detail as possible, including any relevant code, otherwise we won't be able to help you much.

Comment: See above, I have added a picture

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for `-1` for someone who made it. The response does not give a name for value with this  `_` symbol. When I have change `access_token` on a `token` , all is working